# GCalendar search in my complete calendar / full calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar

I have created this script to manage my own calendar. To find the affected timeslots I have created this simple script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("MyCalendar@googlemail.com");
    
  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("June 26, 2018 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("July 18, 2025 23:59:59 CST"),{search: 'MyCalendarTest'});
  
  var max = events.length;
  
  Logger.log(cal);
  
  for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    events[i].setColor("5");    // Yellow
  }
}
```

Is it possible to create the command for searching without any timelimit (start/end time)?

Answer (score 2):

What you want can be achieved by using the `Calendar` advanced service.

You need to turn the **Calendar API** service on by going to your project's *Resources* > *Advanced Google services...*

[image: advanced google services]

Afterwards, look for the **Calendar API** in the list and activate it. As it can be seen on the third column, you can call the service by using `Calendar`.

[image]

Then, just use the below snippet

```
function getEvents() {
   var eventsList = Calendar.Events.list('CALENDAR_ID');
   var allEvents = eventsList.items;
   for (var i=0; i<allEvents.length; i++)
      console.log(allEvents[i].summary)
}
```

This will return the summary of all the events you have. Please bear in mind that this can customized in order to return all the parameters you need for an event.

#### Reference

- [Advanced Google Services Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced);
- [Calendar API Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list).

Comment: Hello, thanks so much - it is so easy. I have to get used to work with the Advanced Google Services.
Why are such basic functions not included in basic scripting?

Comment: Advanced services are basically used to connect directly to the API - so all the methods used by the advanced services are specific to the ones from the API. @J.Doe

Comment: Also, for reasons of documentation - kindly mark as accepted the answer which helped you the most. Cheers! @J.Doe

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, all [getEvents()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#geteventsstarttime,-endtime) methods require a date parameter:

[image: explanation]

I am not sure if there is a better or more clever approach but you can use two arbitrary dates like that:

```
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date(1900,1,1), new Date(2100,1,1),{search: 'MyCalendarTest'});
```

that will give you all the calendar events from **1900 until 2100** of the given search value.

Just keep in mind, that if you have **series** of same events, these events will be taken into account in the total number of events.

Comment: Hello, thanks so much - I didn't want to go exactly this way with the date :). But the Advanced Google Service incluse exact what I want.
Why are such basic functions not included in basic scripting?